# terraform to retry local-exec incase failed

Tags: terraform

Terraform to retry local-exec in case failed at first attempt . 
Example Here I am trying to install python on Azure Linux VM using az vm run-command . I do not have ssh access to VM , so I am using Azure API call on https using az cli . Due to network issue sometimes download packages or binary fails and need to rerun . With terraform ,it fails in case such issues. In ansible we have the option to retry but I am not able to find such solution for terraform
Ansible code which supports retry

Ansible code :

> ---
>
> ```
> - hosts: 127.0.0.1
> connection: local
> tasks:
> name: Install App
> shell: |
>   yum install myapp
> register: task_result
> until: task_result.rc == 0
> retries: 2
> delay: 5
> ignore_errors: yes
> ```

```
Terraform code
enter code here
#Install python27-python-pip 
resource "null_resource" "prerequisites" {
  depends_on = [ "null_resource.zipfile" ]
    provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "az vm run-command invoke -g 
'${azurerm_virtual_machine.myserver.resource_group_name}' -n 
'${azurerm_virtual_machine.myserver.resource_group_name}' -- 
command-id RunShellScript --scripts 'yum -y install python27-python- 
pip && scl enable python27 bash >> /tmp/install.log'"
on_failure = "fail"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ansible and Terraform do two very different things.

- Terraform is an infrastructure provisioning system.
- Ansible is a software configuration system.

Ideally you would use BOTH. Use Terraforms local-exec to run the Ansible playbook. Thus both infra and software end up in the state you desire. `Right tool right job`.